# Efficient way to calculate all IoUs of two lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function to calculate the IoU of two rectangles/bounding boxes.

```
def intersection_over_union(boxA, boxB):
    # determine the (x, y)-coordinates of the intersection rectangle
    xA = max(boxA[0], boxB[0])
    yA = max(boxA[1], boxB[1])
    xB = min(boxA[2], boxB[2])
    yB = min(boxA[3], boxB[3])

    # compute the area of intersection rectangle
    interArea = max(0, xB - xA + 1) * max(0, yB - yA + 1)

    # compute the area of both the prediction and ground-truth
    # rectangles
    boxAArea = (boxA[2] - boxA[0] + 1) * (boxA[3] - boxA[1] + 1)
    boxBArea = (boxB[2] - boxB[0] + 1) * (boxB[3] - boxB[1] + 1)

    # compute the intersection over union by taking the intersection
    # area and dividing it by the sum of prediction + ground-truth
    # areas - the interesection area
    iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea)

    # return the intersection over union value
    return iou
```

Now I want to calculate all IoUs of bboxes of one list with bboxes of another list, i.e. if list A containts 4 bboxes and list B contains 3 bboxes, then I want a 4x3 matrix with all possible IoUs as a result.

Of course I can do this with two loops like this

```
import numpy as np

n_i = len(bboxes_a)
n_j = len(bboxes_b)
iou_mat = np.empty((n_i, n_j))
for i in range(n_i):
    for j in range(n_j):
        iou_mat[i, j] = intersection_over_union(bboxes_a[i], bboxes_b[j])
```

but this approach is very slow, especially when the lists become very big.

I'm struggling to find a more efficient way. There has to be a way to utilize numpy to get rid of the loops, but I don't get it. Also the complexity right now is O(m*n). Is there a possibility to reduce the complexity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**vectorize:**

```
low = np.s_[...,:2]
high = np.s_[...,2:]

def iou(A,B):
    A,B = A.copy(),B.copy()
    A[high] += 1; B[high] += 1
    intrs = (np.maximum(0,np.minimum(A[high],B[high])
                        -np.maximum(A[low],B[low]))).prod(-1)
    return intrs / ((A[high]-A[low]).prod(-1)+(B[high]-B[low]).prod(-1)-intrs)

AB = iou(A[:,None],B[None])
```

**complexity:**

Since you are calculating M x N values reducing complexity below M x N is impossible unless most of the values are zero and a sparse representation of the matrix is acceptable.

This can be done by argsorting (separately for x and y) all the ends of A and B. That's O((M+N) log(M+N)) **EDIT** As the coordinates are integer linear complexity may be possible here. **EDIT ends** This can then be used to prefilter A x B. The complexity of filtering and computing the nonzeros would be O(M + N + number of nonzeros).

Comment: any reason low and high are external to the function? and what's in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product()` in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) in python to replace a nested for-loop. Using built-in function is always better I think. Examples can be like:

```py
import numpy as np

l1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 4))
l2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4))
print(f'l1:\n{l1}')
print(f'l2:\n{l2}')


from itertools import product

ious = np.array([intersection_over_union(box1, box2) for box1, box2 in product(l1, l2)]).reshape(len(l2), len(l1))
print(f'ious:\n{ious}')
```

**What's more, you should change** `iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea)` **to** `iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea + np.finfo(float).eps)` **to avoid** `divided by zero error.`